# <td> rendering issue in IE8

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table, internet-explorer-8

When setting a td's display in a table to none, the table does not resize properly in IE8.

If I have a table, and I remove an entire column with something like this :

```
$("th:first, th:last, tr td:first-child, tr td:last-child").toggle(0);
```

It works in all browsers, except IE8, keeps the remaining cells scrunched in their original widths and does not resize to the width of the available space.

Anyone know what is not working here?

Comment: Try adding an arbitrary class to the table itself; that should force a repaint.

Comment: Hmm.. I did a .toggleClass(), but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an answer.. but I'm interested in here others:

Ok so the following does not work

```
$("table").hide().show();
```

But this does work :

```
$("table").hide().fadeIn(0);
```